# How to create record with specifying foreign key?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have Users and Bets tables as 1:M relations. However, I didn't want to have any Bet record without User reference.

[image]

So I have the following constrained relations:

```
Bet.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false
    }
});
User.hasMany(Bet);
```

This is creating foreign key in `Bets` which can't be null. 
This is how I intend to create Bet record:

```
User.findOne({
    where: {email: 'aaa@bbb.ccc'}
}).then(u => {
    Bet.create({
        User: u,
        ...
    })
    .then(b => {
        console.log('done');
    });
})
```

Is there any way to specify User while creating Bet? I know I could do it with `<foreignkey>: u.id`, but I wonder if there is a way to do it on higher level, like using `include` and not explicitly referring to foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In defining a relation between `User` and `Bet` you'll have gained some [association methods](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/has-many.js~HasMany.html) on those models.

Using the [create](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/associations/has-many.js~HasMany.html#instance-method-create) method you can instead create a new `Bet` from the `User` instance which will both create a new `Bet` in the DB *and* associate it to the `User`.

```
User.findOne({
    where: { email: 'aaa@bbb.ccc' }
})
    .then(user =>
    {
        user.createBet({ ... })
            .then(bet =>
            {
                console.log('done');
            });
    });
```

Comment: Brilliant! I knew there has to be a way. Thanks!